# Migrate SQL Server Tables to Sharepoint Lists

Tags: c#, sharepoint, data-importer

I have some tables (aprox 200) i want migrate and include in Sharepoint lists. I need a automatic process, anyone have a tool or code to generate sharepoint list based on tables?

Or please give some links for can help me in my demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you will find a tool that will do the whole job.

What you could do is to import each table in to excel, then export it from excel to a sharepoint list.

http://www.sharepointcustomization.com/wss/articles/lists-excel.htm

Hope this helps

Shiraz

Comment: Convert 200 tables to excel is a hard task. Don't exist another solution?

Comment: You could automate the conversion using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)